# Localstorage counter

Tags: javascript, html, stack-overflow

Here is a JavaScript localstorage counter code:

```js
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_counter');
  if (n === null) {
    n = 0;
  }
  n++;
  localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", n);
  document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = n;
  if (n > 3) {
    alert('3rd time');
    return;
  }
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

This code is not working. Where is the problem?
How to solve it?
If we remove web storage support checking code, the other code works greatly.

Comment: All goes fine if you wrap the code into a function (`return` statement is only allowed in the function body).

Comment: @raina77ow please edit the code and post it as answer, so that I can get what wanted and also, I can close this question as answered.

Comment: But why the problem you've shown in the code has nothing to do with `typeof(Storage)` check?

Comment: @raina77ow maybe. But still the code is not working and I have to make it working

Answer (score 0):

When I tried removing return; in JavaScript, the code worked perfectly.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_counter');
    if (n === null) {
      n = 0;
    }
    n++;

    localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", n);
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = n;
    if (n > 3) {
      alert('3rd time');
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
</script>
```